# Can someone explain what is wrong with this OpenCL program?

Tags: c, multithreading, kernel, opencl, gpu

I've included the main parts of the host program which I suspect to be incorrect here:

http://pastebin.com/qVkv9E11

I'm not that great with pointers yet and think I may have allocated some variables wrong.

Here is the Kernel program which should give an idea of what my program is trying to do:

```
    const char *KernelSource =           "\n"
"__kernel void sumElements(           \n"
"   __global float* input,            \n"
"   __global float output,            \n"
"   __global int N)                   \n"
"{                                    \n"
"   int i = get_global_id(0);         \n"
"   if(i < N)                         \n"
"       output += input[i];           \n"
"}                                    \n"
"\n";
```

Perhaps this is causing the error as I've never tried SIMT writing to one variable as above. Is it possible to do such a thing? I need to get the sum of all the elements in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to actually read back the value of output, then you need to declare it as a pointer too.  Right now the value of output is copied in as a kernel argument, but any changes you make to it are ignored after the kernel ends.

So, change `__global float output` to `__global float* output`.  Then in your kernel  change:

```
if(i < N)
    output += input[i];
```

to

```
if(i < N)
    *output += input[i];
```

You may need to change the way you're allocating your buffers for this to work, but it's been a long time since I've done this in OpenCL and the documentation I'm finding right now doesn't show any glaring errors in your buffers.

A word of warning here: addition is *not* an atomic operation.  With this setup, what is invariably going to happen is you're going to have two or more threads reading the value of *output, then trying to write *output + 1 back into it at different stages.  Thus, *output will have a value that is smaller than it should.

To fix this, you're going to need to use OpenCL [atomic operations.](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_add.html)

Comment: Just to add to Telgin's answer, summing individual elements like this is very inefficient (although technically achievable using atomic operations). You may want to consider reducing the problem: for example if your input has N elements, create I work items each responsible for summing N/I elements, then either (i) output an array of partial sums, which are then accumulated back on the host (ii) use an OpenCL memory barrier and have one work item accumulate the partial sums on the device before outputting a single value.

Comment: Excellent! Changed the variables to pointers as you described. I take it having * succeed a variable type makes it a pointer and preceding the variable dereferences it?

And you were right about atomic operations. Only getting back 1 now. I'll do some reading.

Comment: @Chucky Yes, that's correct.  Having a * in the variable declaration makes it a pointer, and using the * operator on it afterward dereferences it by accessing the value at the pointer.  Also, James Beilby is correct in that this is very inefficient, and once you're comfortable that you have this working as intended, you should go read up on reductions to make this much faster.

Comment: At the moment I'm getting an "atomicAdd/atomic_add is undefined". I've read that no include statement is necessary but rather this should be entered on the command line: $nvcc -arch=sm_11 glmax.cu -o glmax

I tried that on my MacBook and nvcc is not recognised. Do either of you happen to know how atomic operations configured on OSX?

Comment: On Linux at least you need to add `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable` at the beginning of your kernel to enable some of the atomics.  Did you try that?  It's probably the same for OSX.